# React useEffect API Call Returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, fetch-api

I'm trying to make a fetch request to my backend API in React using UseEffect. But my data is undefined. When I console log my res.json(), I get a pending, fulfilled promise, so I think that means I'm on the right track.

However, after that step, it returns undefined.

Here's my error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

Here is my code. Please help!

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"
// import { useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom"
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate"
import Record from "../components/Record"
import FieldName from "../components/FieldName"

const Index = (props) => {
    // let data = useLoaderData()

    const[data, setData] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch("https://backendurl.com/data", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        }).then((res) => {
            console.log(res.json())
        }).then((data) => {
            setData(data)
        }).catch((error) => console.log(error))
    })

    return <div className="records">
                {data.map((record) =>
                    <Record record={record} key={record.record_id} />
                )}
           </div>
}

export default Index
```

Comment: Well `console.log(res.json())` returns `undefined`, and so does the function it's in, making `data` in the next step `undefined`. Replace that by `return res.json()` - and possibly add `console.log(data)` in the next `then` callback - and it'll work.

Comment: @Bergi Wow. Can't believe I was just missing a return keyword. Thank you so much!

Comment: You should also add an empty dependency array to your effect hook. Otherwise it will execute on every render

Comment: @Phil Oh I forgot about that. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to map the empty array. This is main problem. It is caused due to the fact that the useEffect updating the state, but the component rerenders as state has been changed. However, your useEffect runs again, and it is stuck in a cycle. You have to provide the dependency array for useEffect, and the dependancy array should be empty []. By stating like that, you are telling useEffect run only once and it will update the state only one time, after receiving fulfilled